# Why is non-existent image working on kubernetes deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

First I have created two different version of image as below

> docker image ls

```
REPOSITORY     |    TAG      |    IMAGE ID
isaac88/posts  |    0.0.1    |    xxx
isaac88/posts  |    0.0.5    |    yyy
```

Then I created a kubernetes deployment file as below

> posts-depl.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: posts-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: posts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: posts
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: posts
          image: isaac88/posts:0.0.1
```

If you noticed, I specified version of image in deployment yaml file. by swapping the version between `0.0.1` and `0.0.5` and executed below commands to see the differences

1. `kubectl apply -f posts-depl.yaml`
2. `kubectl get pods`
3. `kubectl logs xxxxxxxxx`

Everything works fine so far.

Now I've tried to remove `0.0.1` from the deployment yaml, i'm wondering on how it behaves since I do not have a latest version being tagged to my docker image. I've verified using `docker image ls`

Below is my latest `yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: posts-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: posts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: posts
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: posts
          image: isaac88/posts
```

After removed the version, I've ran `kubectl apply -f posts-depl.yaml` and surprisingly it is able to create the deployment successfully, and I went ahead and executed `kubectl logs xxxxx` on latest pods created, I see the logs which are belongs to version `0.0.1`. I don't understand the reason behind

Comment: Can you please check whether there is an `isaac88/posts:latest` image on the node which runs the pod of this deployment?

Answer (score 3):

That is because your deployment failed to fetch image with the latest tag
and rolled back to the previous version of the deployment where you have specified tag 0.0.1

Rolling updates are the default strategy to update the running version of your app.

You can read more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-back-a-deployment)

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because the deployment is still using the old image. Check if there was failed image pull event by using `kubectl get events` and deployment history using `kubectl rollout history deployment.v1.apps/posts-depl`.

Check which image is currently being used in the deployment by `kubectl describe deployment posts-depl`